# More-Routing multiple path for one name

Tags: routes, polymer, polymer-1.0

I want to route the user to the `home` screen as shown in the below example.

My problem is that more-routing does not allow multiple routing paths for a single `name`.

How to create something like otherwise in angularjs?

When all not valid path are going into the `name="home"`

```
<more-route name="home" path="/home"></more-route>
<more-route name="home" path="/home/:mutation"></more-route>
<more-route name="home" path="/home/words/:mutation/:hu"></more-route>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
<more-route name="home" path="/home">
  <more-route name="mutation" path="/:mutation"></more-route>  
  <more-route name="words" path="/words/:mutation/:hu"></more-route>
</more-route>

<more-route-selector selectedParams="{{params}}">
  <iron-pages>
    <section route="home">
      <template if="{{ route('mutation').active }}">
        ...
      </template>
      <template if="{{ route('words').active }}">
        ...
      </template>
    </section>
  </iron-pages>
</more-route-selector>
```

Comment: No, I want that all three path above points to the same section in the code. It shouldn't be count if i am arriving from url/home or url/home/:mutation at the end i have to see the same page.

Comment: The above example will do that.  All three paths will take you to `<section route="home">`. The two `template`s inside just give you the opportunity to work with the params specific to those paths if you wish.